# Update pdf which is open in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm creating pdf file using DOM pdf, it is working but when i try to recreate it with same name and the pdf file is open then i'm getting this error message:

> message:  exception: "ErrorException" file:
> "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxxx\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php"
> line:
> 199"file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\XXXX\storage\app\public/pdf/salary/40_file-2021.pdf):
> failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable" trace:
> [{function: "handleError", class:
> "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions", type: "->"},…]

```
             $dompdf = new Dompdf();
             $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
             $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);  
             $html = view('admin/pdf',['data'=>$data_new])->render();
             $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
             $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
             $dompdf->render();
             $fileName = 'pdf/salary/'.$data_new->user_id.'_'.$data_new->application_id.'.pdf';
             Storage::put('public/'.$fileName, $dompdf->output());
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try delete file first if exists?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either:

1. Close the open PDF before attempting to overwrite it
2. Write the new PDF to a different location (and probably delete the old PDF after closing it)